# How to make InDesign's epub file vs. PDF file compatible?

Tags: pdf, filesize, epub, adobe-indesign

We used Adobe inDesign to design story books.  We need both the PDF file as well as epub file. Since we all view in PDF during the process, the final clear product in PDF, when we export as epub file, it's huge.  It all messed up the original design.  What can we do?
Why did it happen?

Comment: PDF is a **final** presentation format, designed for viewing, printing, etc. It is not meant to be used for storing documents that will be edited again later on or exported into other formats.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked on ONE project going from InDesign to ePub about two years ago - and you are right it is a mess. It didn't understand which local overrides to keep and practically every paragraph had `style="localoverride1 localoverride2 substyle3 etc"` in it. It was a mess to sort and clean up.

After that miserable experience we've found that it is better to view PDF and ePub as two separate products. Our workflow takes source XML and goes EITHER into InDesign OR through an XSLT to make an ePub. We no longer use InDesign to attempt to make ePubs - with an XSLT there is a LOT more control over the look and feel of the final product.

However if you are dead set on using InDesign - I've heard that it does fixed layout "epub" fairly well (basically it ends up being a bunch of images - it's not reflowable).